# Two definitions of principal fiber

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, principal-bundles

I have two definition of $G$-principal fiber bundle when $G$ is a linear algebraic group complex. Let be $X$ a complex variety.

> A principal fiber bundle on $X$ is a couple ($\xi,q$) where $\xi$ is a complex variety and $q: \xi\rightarrow X$ a morphism such that:
>
> i) there is an action of G on $\xi$ such that the fiber $q^{-1}(X)$ are fixed
>
> ii) is locally trivial: for each $x \in X$ exists $x \in U \subset X$ neighborhood of $x$ in $X$ and am isomorphism $\psi_{U}:q^{-1}(U) \rightarrow G \times U$ such that $\psi_{U}$ is $G$-equviariant
>
> the $G$ action is free and transitive

The second definition is as the first but without the third axiom, so I would like to know if it's a real axiom and if there are some examples of principal fiber bundle which are graphically significative

Comment: Take an action of a group on a space which is not free and transitive. Then, this can be considered as a bundle over a point satisfying 1 and 2 but not 3.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see your point what is

Comment: I'd also be interested in an anwer. I think the $G$-equivariance of bundle charts should imply freeness and transitivity, since the achtion of $G$ on $G\times U$ has these properties. The example above does not admit an equivariant chart. Have you figured it out?

Comment: @LuckyS - when you pose this question to "algebraic geometers" people will ask you: What type of "language" do you use. Do you view $X$ as a (quasi projective) algebraic variety in the sense of Hartshorne, ChI?